# How to apply second geometric form of hahn-banach to prove that exists a functional with norm one and has a specific value at a specific point.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I'm struggling to manage how to solve this problem:
\begin{aligned}
&\text { Let } M \text { be a proper closed subspace of a normed vector space } E \text { . Let } u_{0} \in E \text { such that }\\
&\operatorname{dist}\left(u_{0}, M\right)=\inf _{v \in M}\left\|u_{0}-v\right\|=d>0 . \text { Prove that there exists } \varphi \in E^{\prime} \text { such that } \varphi\left(u_{0}\right)=d\\
&\left.\varphi\right|_{M}=0 \text { and }\|\varphi\|_{E^{\prime}}=1.
\end{aligned}

The main idea that i had to prove this problem is, consider $[\varphi = d]$, and try to prove that is the hyperplan which cuts E in two. Since i have the distance between $u_0$ and $M$, it clearly separates $u_0$ and $M$.  This part $\varphi|_{M}=0$ is already proved. But why $\varphi(u_0)=d$ and its norm is one i'm not able to see it.  I don't know if my idea is correct, i wish some tips to finish this proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the quotient space $F=E/M.$ Since $M$ is closed therefore $F$ is an Banach space. Let $\xi : E\to F$, $\xi (u) =[u]_M =u+M$ be a quotient map which is obviously continuous.
Since $||[u_0 ]||_F = d$ therefore by Hahn Banach theorem there exist a $\kappa \in F'$ such that $||\kappa ||=1$ and $\kappa ([u_0 ])= d.$
Now is enough to observe that $\varphi =\kappa \circ \xi $ satisfies the conditions of your exercise.